# Rename Text Label of hyperlinks in Google Sheets

Tags: hyperlink, google-sheets, rename

I'm using a Google Form to upload receipts to Google Sheets. The resulting document provides me with a nice link to the uploaded image file in Google Drive. I have been searching for a script that I could edit that would change the text label on each of the hyperlinks to "Receipt" without it changing the link itself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link to see how you can best ask a question. As it stands, your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

If A1:A500 had the hyperlinks, Then, B1

```
   =ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK(A1:A500, "RECEIPT"))
```

Copy this and Paste "Values ONLY" back in A1:A500

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the current top solution is to use their HYPERLINK formula https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en. E.g. if column A had the hyper links and you wanted the name to be "RECEIPT," put the following formula in B1:
`=HYPERLINK(A1, "RECEIPT")`

Then drag the bottom right corner to replicate for all cells in column B. Alternatively if you had a list of link names in column C, instead input `=HYPERLINK(A1, C1)`.

This solution has the benefit of letting you sort by any column without the rows breaking, which isn't the case with `ARRAYFORMULA`. Unfortunately neither solution seems to work with pasting Values Only.